# Deployment package did not contain an iisApp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to upload a zip of files of a published .net project to Amazon elastic beanstalk but it keeps throwing an error in the logs saying iisApp is not there.  How to fix?

Answer (score 6):

Elastic Beanstalk expects a WebDeploy package, not just a zipped web application. You'll probably want to run:

```
msbuild <web.csproj> /t:Package /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageLocation=<outputdirectory>
```

to create a WebDeploy package.

Comment: I was just trying to do a simple HTML page, but this makes sense why it isn't for me. I changed to Tomcat and it was fine after that. Thanks!